# gitpython to prune local branches

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

I am trying to achieve `git remote prune origin` through gitpython. I am able to get the branches to delete by using `Repo(path).remote('origin').stale_refs`.

Any idea how can I prune these?

Answer (score 1):

From my empirical attempts, it seem this works:

```
repo = git.Repo(path)
for branch in repo.remote('origin').stale_refs:
  if isinstance(branch, git.refs.remote.RemoteReference):
    type(branch).delete(repo, branch)
  else:
    pass  # it seems stale_refs can include tags (etc?)
```